# Put checks at multiple points in Python code to trigger an email if the code fails

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am using win32com.client to trigger an outlook email to myself from Python.I have that figured out and created a function to trigger emails which works.
Now, I want to put multiple checks in my python code so that I can get email notifications if my code fails in that section.

The logical flow is Something like this:

```
if code between lines 1 to 50 fails:
    Send email with the message that data read failed
if code between lines 51 to 200 fails:
    Send email with the message that the algorithm failed
if code between lines 201 to 300 fails:
    Send email with the message that the write failed
```

Comment: use `try-catch` ?

Comment: Your method of using line numbers isn't dynamic enough for changes in the script. Or if for example a linter changes the lines in the code. You should wrap your code in try catches or create Exceptions yourself.

Answer (score 2):

You can create a function, or one for each specific task, e.g., `read_data`, `algo`, and `write_output`. If something goes wrong an exception will be raised. Then, you can catch the exception and send the email accordingly.

```
class ReadFailed(Exception):
   pass
```

---

```
def my_function():
   raise ReadFailed('read has failed')
```

---

```
try:
    my_function()
except ReadFailed:
    send_email('data_failed')
except AlgoFailed:
     send_email('algo_failed')
except WriteFailed:
     send_email('write_failed')
```

Answer (score 0):

To extract error line number:

```py
import sys

try:
    x!=56
except:
    lineno = sys.exc_info()[-1].tb_lineno
    print(lineno)
    if(0<=lineno<50): do_something_50()
    elif(50<=lineno<100): do_something_100()
    elif(100<=lineno<150): do_something_150()
    else: ...
```

Outputs:

```py
4
```